# Rav S.Z. Auerbach on Toveling Tables and Refrigerator Shelves

Tags: halacha, tevilas-keilim-dipping, rav-shlomo-z-auerbach

According to Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach, *z"l*, as [cited](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kof-k.org%2Farticles%2F040108090413W-3%2520Tevilas%2520Keilim.pdf) by the Kof-K, tables do not require *tevila*.  However, he is cited in the same Kof-K article as having seemingly allowed omitting *tevila* of refrigerator shelves only because they are part of the appliance:

> Refrigerator Shelves- If the food is not placed on these shelves directly there is no requirement for tevilah. Be’er Moshe 4:99, Tevilas Keilim 11:10, Minchas Shlomo 2:66:8, Shalmei Moed page 555. Some say it is always exempt because it is butel to the refrigerator (Shalmei Moed ibid).

What reasoning is employed by Rav Shlomo Zalman, z"l, to rule leniently with regard to tables (that apparently isn't usable by shelves)?

Comment: Have you checked the sefer to see what he actually says?

Comment: A table is also part of an ~appliance. The entirety of one, actually. How do you see he's treating it differently from shelves?

Comment: @msh210 Is that what he says? My understanding is that even large and unwieldy *keilim* still require tevila - which is why in some cases poskim are lenient to allow Jewish factories to have certain untovelables to be "borrowed" from a gentile. I thought perhaps he was using similar reasoning to Rav Nachum Rabinovitch, shlit"a, a la the Chazon Ish on boneh, that plugged devices are mechubar.

Comment: @msh210 I also think a table, especially a small one, is moved more frequently than a refrigerator.

Comment: (re your comment of 4:50:10 UTC) Then I second what @Ploni said.

Comment: @Ploni I don't own the sefer and can't seem to find it online (except the first half of the sentence on google books)