# Does an ice machine need tevilah?

Tags: halacha, mikvah-ritual-bath

Does an ice machine need to be dipped in the mikvah if it's built from stainless steel?

Comment: Why do you ask only about an ice machine and not simply about a refrigerator (or an oven), in which unwrapped food is cooled / heated?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84119/rav-s-z-auerbach-on-toveling-tables-and-refrigerator-shelves

Comment: I assume you mean to ask about it ignoring the general dispute about electrical appliances? Like, if we found a non-electric ice machine that is portable, and wouldn't break if submerged, and doesn't connect to the ground, would it be obligated?

Answer (score 0):

There are  opinions that electrical appliances do not require tevila as they are not keilim as well as if an item is not portable it would not require tevila either.

[Here](https://www.kof-k.org/articles/040108090413w-3%20tevilas%20keilim.pdf) is a source that talks about some of the laws in regards to what you must tovel.

Comment: Not all ice makers aren't portable. https://www.walmart.com/ip/Igloo-Compact-Portable-Ice-Maker-ICE108-White/55734066?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=0&adid=22222222252394788415&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=m&wl3=273221277985&wl4=pla-293946777986&wl5=9004365&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=1&wl9=showcase_product&wl10=117019096&wl11=online&wl12=55734066&wl13=&veh=sem&wl18=showcase

Comment: I have something similar to this and the part which actually touches the water and ice is plastic. Additionally not all opinions require electrical appliances to be toveled as they aren't considered kelim or bc there is room to be lenient if it will destroy the item being that toveling now is midivre sofrim